# Explanation for kernel error - Eeeek! page_mapcount went negative

Tags: linux, centos, server-crashes

Internet says this is a genuine Kernel Bug but does anyone know what triggers it??

Server running CentOS x86_64 with kernel  2.6.27.24

Here is my crash output:

```
[root@u15345757 httpdocs]#
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.506380] Eeek! page_mapcount(page) went negative! (-1)
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.517515] page pfn = d0a3
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.523814] page->flags = 10000000000083c
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.532489] page->count = 2
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.538741] page->mapping = ffff88001f01a110
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.547924] vma->vm_ops = 0x0
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:22 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.554543] [ cut here ]
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:23 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.564528] invalid opcode: 0000 [1] SMP
Message from syslogd@ at Thu Aug 6 01:42:23 2009 ...
u15345757 kernel: [1145736.564528] Code: 80 e8 22 51 fd ff 48 8b 85 90 00 00 00 48 85 c0 74 19 48 8b 40 20 48 85 c0 74 10 48 8b 70 58 48 c7 c7 10 7f 7d 80 e8 fd 50 fd ff <0f> 0b eb fe 8b 77 18 41 58 5b 5d 83 e6 01 f7 de 83 c6 04 e9 df
Broadcast message from root (pts/3) (Thu Aug 6 01:49:29 2009):

The system is going down for reboot NOW!
```

Comment: A *CentOS* installation with kernel 2.6.27.24? What? CentOS either runs 2.6.18 or 2.6.9. Where does this kernel come from?

Comment: Is this vanilla kernel ? How much memory and swap do you have ? give here output of:
sysctl -a | grep vm.swappiness

Answer (score 1):

This is not a standard kernel for CentOS, which means it can be any number of issues.  If you truly need to run this particular, non standard kernel for CentOS I suggest following [this guide](http://www.av8n.com/computer/htm/kernel-lockup.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to run memcheck to discard failing memory. Otherwise it could be a cosmic bit flipping, or a genuine kernel bug.

Then it depends of the workflow you were having at that time (was it CPU hungry? FS hungry? etc.) Some workflows are more likely to trigger faulty RAM.